# English equivalent for "An ignorant child learns when it itches"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

In my language, there's a saying which literally translates to

> **"An ignorant child learns when it itches."**

It's a kind of warning that means

> If people refuse to realise the magnitude of a problem when there is time to solve it, they will only realize it when they're forced to deal with the repercussions.

Consider this scene I imagined.

> Family goes camping; kid touches a poisonous plant ignoring parents warning; results in itchy rash on skin.

Thus, the idiom might've originated.

I found this to have a meaning somewhat close.

> [**Learn the hard way**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+the+hard+way)
>
> To learn something by experience, especially by an unpleasant experience.

But I wonder if there's a better phrase to use when warning somebody before it's too late.

Comment: Extending the phrase you already have, there's the saying "Some people have to learn the hard way."

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, they do. That's one way to say it. I think that's the simplest version yet.

Comment: I think of this as diving into the pool to see if there's any water.  But that's personal.  I don't know of a proverb.  This culture tends to respect learning by experience.  For example "Once bitten, twice shy."  or "If you learn something the hard way you don't forget it."

Comment: And, of course, there is the "school of hard knocks".

Comment: Maybe "We learn not in/at school, but in life" https://archive.org/stream/dictionaryoflati1891rileuoft/dictionaryoflati1891rileuoft_djvu.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two entirely different approaches here.

First, is there a literal equivalent of the saying? Sure.

> The burned hand avoids the flame.
>
> Good judgement comes from experience. Experience comes from bad judgement.
>
> The wise man learns from someone else’s mistakes, the smart man learns
>   from his own, but a fool will have no teacher.
>
> Hindsight is 20/20.
>
> Too soon old, too late smart.

As for the meaning you give,

> An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.

Answer (score 4):

***once bitten, twice shy***

> Once hurt, one is doubly cautious in the future, as in *He was two days late last time, so she's not hiring him again—once bitten, twice shy*. This seemingly old observation, presumably alluding to an animal biting someone, was first recorded in 1894.
> [The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/once-bitten--twice-shy)

Some other sayings that might be worth considering,

> *No man learns but by pain or shame*
>
> *We learn not in/at school, but in life*
>
> *What you learn to your cost you remember long* ([*Danish saying*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=VHAbAQAAIAAJ&q=%22cost+you+remember+long%22&dq=%22cost+you+remember+long%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO0J_MwaTMAhVIFCwKHecEAjUQ6AEIVTAI))

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind for me is:

> a stitch in time saves nine

which means that what you do now can reduce later hardships. It generally is a warning against procrastination rather than impending problems, however.

Similarly:

> make hay while the sun shines

or

> that which rests now bites later

Comment: +1 for effort. But these sound more like **grab the opportunity** than **you'll suffer for not listening to me**.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen various campaigns that say **"ACT NOW BEFORE IT'S TOO LATE"**!

However I am not sure if this is an idiom.

You can perhaps simply say ***[it's now or never](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/now+or+never)***

> at this time and no other

[The Free Dictionary]

For example,

> Jane, if you want to get fit, then you have to cut down on the junk food exercise. It's **now or never**!

Comment: +1 for effort, but it's not exactly on track.

Answer (score 1):

The following proverb is quite close to "an ignorant child  learns when it itches":

> **Your best teacher is your last mistake.**

[image]

As the proverb applies to past errors rather than warnings, you may caution the child by using the idiom **"kick yourself"**, that means *to be ​annoyed because you did something ​stupid or ​failed to ​act when you had an ​opportunity*.

> For example: Do it now! Otherwise, you ​know you’ll kick yourself if
>   you ​forget to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> Pay now or pay later.

Didn't find a nifty explanation on the internet but did find countless examples, such as [*Pay Now or Pay Later: Autism Families in Crisis*](http://www.parl.gc.ca/Content/SEN/Committee/391/soci/rep/repfinmar07-e.pdf). The inset quote on page 11 spells it out pretty well, in applying this general idiom to an actual monetary subject:

> (...) if you pay for it now, look at the return you will get on your investment. ... Or you can pay later, ... and it will cost the taxpayers a lot of money in the long run ....
>   
>  – Jason Oldford, *Fredericton*, New Brunswick (12:32)